# Enable/Disable textarea with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox

My task is to use JavaScript to enable the   when the checkbox is clicked (on) and disable it when it is clicked (off).
However, the code still isn't working, and won't do anything regardless of whether I click the checkbox or not.

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2> Order Information </h2>
<div class="entry">
  Select color:
  <select name="color">
    <option selected="selected">White</option>
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  Select shirt size:
  <select name="sizeandprice">
    <option>Small - $9.99</option>
    <option>Medium - $10.99</option>
    <option selected="selected">Large - $11.99</option>
    <option>X-Large - $13.99</option>
  </select><br><br>
  Is this a gift? <input type="checkbox" name="gift"> <br><br>
  Write your gift message here: <br>
  <textarea disabled rows="5" cols="50" name="message">Type your message here.
  </textarea>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the Javascript code:

```
function enable(x) {
    x = document.getElementbyId("gift");
    x.checked
    if(x == true) {
        var textarea = document.getElementbyId("message");
        textarea.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        var textarea = document.getElementbyId("message");
        textarea.disabled = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('giftCheckbox').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    var textArea = document.getElementById('messageTxtArea')
    textArea.disabled = !textArea.disabled
});
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2> Order Information </h2>
<div class="entry">
  Select color:
  <select name="color">
    <option selected="selected">White</option>
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  Select shirt size:
  <select name="sizeandprice">
    <option>Small - $9.99</option>
    <option>Medium - $10.99</option>
    <option selected="selected">Large - $11.99</option>
    <option>X-Large - $13.99</option>
  </select><br><br>
  Is this a gift? <input type="checkbox" id="giftCheckbox" name="gift"> <br><br>
  Write your gift message here: <br>
  <textarea disabled rows="5" cols="50" id="messageTxtArea" name="message">Type your message here.
  </textarea>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

I added ids to your checkbox and textarea. I use **.addEventListener()** to register a callback on your checkbox click event, that enables/disables the textarea element.

Comment: Please don't post answers on 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include a "code snippet" right in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your function is never being called. You need to bind a `click` event callback function that invokes `enable`.  You also need some other code tweaks - see comments inline:

```js
// Get reference to checkbox and textarea just once, not over and over
// Also, you were using .getElementById(), but your elements weren't 
// given id's, they have names
var chk = document.querySelector("input[name=gift]");   // id is not "gift", name is
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea[name=message"); // id is not "message", name is

// Set up click event handler:
chk.addEventListener("click", enable);

function enable() {
    // Just base the disabled of the textarea on the opposite 
    // of the checkbox's checked state
    textarea.disabled = !this.checked;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<h2> Order Information </h2>
<div class="entry">
  Select color:
  <select name="color">
    <option selected="selected">White</option>
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  Select shirt size:
  <select name="sizeandprice">
    <option>Small - $9.99</option>
    <option>Medium - $10.99</option>
    <option selected="selected">Large - $11.99</option>
    <option>X-Large - $13.99</option>
  </select><br><br>
  Is this a gift? <input type="checkbox" name="gift"> <br><br>
  Write your gift message here: <br>
  <textarea disabled rows="5" cols="50" name="message">Type your message here.
  </textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your input type element has been given a attribute `name="gift"` and you are searching for a element which contains `id="gift"`. You can change the attribute from name to id or use `document.getElementsByName("gift")`. See example of usage in [document.document.getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Comment: If he gets rid of `name`, the element won't submit its data with the form. Also, `.getElementsByName()` returns a "live" node list which has limited use cases since it uses more resources. `.querySelectorAll()` is the correct modern approach.