# How do I disable textarea on checkbox click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I disable the textarea onclick of the checkbox?

```
<p>What caused the damage?</p>
<textarea rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox">
<label>I don't know</label>
```

Comment: The only code you've supplied is your basic HTML structure. What JavaScript or jQuery have you attempted to achieve your goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS - Enable/Disable textarea with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125381/js-enable-disable-textarea-with-checkbox)

Comment: That duplicate is almost just a non-related bug in that guy's code, though. An answer here would be more straightforward because the question is.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work as what you intend to achieve.

```
$('#checkbox').on('click', function(){ 
  if($("#checkbox").is(":checked")){ 
        $('#textArea').val('');
        $('#textArea'). attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }else{ 
       $('#textArea').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    } 
   }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textArea = document.querySelector('#text-area');
var checkbox = document.querySelector('#cbox');

function toggleTextArea() {
  var disabled = textArea.getAttribute('disabled');
  if (disabled) {
    textArea.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    textArea.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

checkbox.addEventListener('click', toggleTextArea);
```

```html
<p>What caused the damage?</p>
                      <textarea rows="5" id="text-area"></textarea>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="cbox">
                      <label for="cbox">I don't know</label>
```

Comment: What about if he unchecked again?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `disabled` property of a `<textarea>` liike `<textarea disabled>`.

```js
let checker = document.getElementById("checker");
let textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");

checker.addEventListener('click', () => textInput.disabled = checker.checked);
```

```html
<p>What caused the damage?</p>
<textarea id="textInput" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="checker">
<label>I don't know</label>
```

Comment: I did it without addEventListener. It seems it helps shortening the code :)

Comment: @muhammadtayyab, using `onclick` is an insecure way. Instead, `addEventListener` provides better security, it's cleaner and most commonly used. Even more, using this you don't mix your `html` with your `js`.

Comment: OK great. I think just provided an alternate version

Answer (score 0):

I just added a JavaScript that selects the text area and enable and disable it based on what your checkbox

```html
<script> 

var flagChk = document.getElementById("chk");
function disableBox(){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").disabled = chk.checked;   
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").enabled = chk.unchecked;
    }

</script>
                     <p>What caused the damage?</p>
                      <textarea rows="5" id="myTextArea"></textarea>
                      <input type="checkbox" onclick="disableBox()" id="chk">
                      <label>I don't know</label>
```

Comment: You can reduce your code by removing the if/else logic and put directly ```document.getElementById("myTextArea").disabled = chk.checked;```

Comment: Thanks I just did it!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Markup consists of a CheckBox and a TextBox which is by default disabled using the disabled attribute. The CheckBox has been assigned a JavaScript OnClick event handler.
When the CheckBox is clicked, the EnableDisableTextBox JavaScript function is executed. Inside this function, based on whether CheckBox is checked (selected) or unchecked (unselected), the TextBox is enabled or disabled by setting the disabled property to false or true respectively.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EnableDisableTextBox(chkPassport) {
        var txtPassportNumber = document.getElementById("txtPassportNumber");
        txtPassportNumber.disabled = chkPassport.checked ? false : true;
        if (!txtPassportNumber.disabled) {
            txtPassportNumber.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
<label for="chkPassport">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkPassport" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)" />
    Do you have Passport?
</label>
<br />
Passport Number:
<input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#checker').click(function(){
     if($("#checker").is(":checked")){
            $('#textInput').attr('disabled',true).val("");
     }else{
        $('#textInput').attr('disabled',false);
     }
 });
```

Comment: There's this one issue. If I write something in the textarea and then disable the textarea the text remains inside. Is there a way that any text written in it also gets removed?